# Writing a specific Clang check

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clang-tidy

I'm trying to implement my little custom check, for example trying to walk through [this tutorial](http://bbannier.github.io/blog/2015/05/02/Writing-a-basic-clang-static-analysis-check.html) (which is out of date a bit).

I have several problems:

- After I cloned the repos, implemented the check and runned cmake, the **builds targets are different** from the tutorial
- After the build and the make of the project I don't even know **what should I run, to execute my checker** on a file or on a project.

Thank you forward for your help!

Comment: Please, describe your **exact steps** in the question post. Linking to the tutorial shows the *reason* of these steps ("**Why** have you performed these steps?" - "I have followed the tutorial"). Currently, your question can be answered only by a person who knows well the tutorial and practicing a lot in it. E.g. you say "builds targets are different from the tutorial." - Which **exact** targets are different? Should we try to follow the tutorial (build our code) for detect that?

Comment: Yes, you should try to follow it. I believe that the same problems will come out for you too.

Comment: You don't quite understand me. Would you say like: "I have cloned repos <list-repos-here> and run `cmake <actual-options>`. But there is no target `Foo`, which is needed for <...>. The tutorial talks about that target.", then a person, who familiar with clang-tidy, but **not familiar with a tutorial**, may answer like: "The target for make these thing is named `Bar`". But currently your question doesn't allow such person to answer - the absent target can only be revealed by following the tutorial. Do not expect everyone *wants* to follow the same tutorial as you for help you.

Comment: - I Cloned the mirror of the repos as written in the tutorial from here, because the ones in the tutorial were not working
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ..
Then I Tried:
make check-clang-tools but I can only run: make check-clang-tooling
After following the tutorial I cannot find the point which shows me how to run my check which I implemented as It is written in it.

Comment: Do not post additional information about your problem in the *comments*. Instead, [edit] the **question post** and add this information into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've **solved** the **build target problem**, which was that the check-clang-tools target were missing. In the cmake file structure, on the `llvm/tools/clang/tools` level, in the `CMakeLists.txt` there was a missing line, which i have to add:
`add_clang_subdirectory(clang-tools-extra)`

---

The **solution** to the **execution problem**:

1. Make sure that the `somedir/llvm/build/bin` is added to your `PATH`
2. Then you need to execute

`llvm/tools/clang/tools/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py
   fileyouwanttocheck.cpp -checks='-*,your-check'`

or

`llvm/tools/clang/tools/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py
   project_folder_you_want_to_check -checks='-*,your-check'`

Answer (score 3):

Well instead of using a tutorial which you admit is out of date how about using a tutorial that is part of the official documentation?

https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/Contributing.html#writing-a-clang-tidy-check

> what should I run, to execute my checker on a file or on a project.

Run the clang-tidy executable with proper parameters (see the aforementioned documentation for more details)

```
$ clang-tidy test.cpp -checks=-*,your-custom-check-name
```

`-*` disables all default checks so this will only run your custom check.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just ran into the same issue and wanted to post my fix:

1. Navigate to your `build_ninja` directory.
2. Run `cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang;clang-tools-extra -GNinja ..\llvm` (This instructs `cmake` to build both `clang` and `clang-tools-extra`)
3. Run `ninja check-clang-tools` (This runs all of the tests for `clang-tools-extra`)